# How to use python cffi library with TI cl2000 compiler?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-cffi

I am trying to use cffi for compiling code written for TI's f28035 microcontroller. Then I'd like to unit test the code with the python unittest library. I need TI's cl2000 compiler instead of visual c++.

I've added the path to cl2000 to my Path variable.
I'm using python 3.8. I've created a distutils.config file with the contents:

```
[build]
compiler = cl2000
```

I've reinstalled cffi with pip and I get the following error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\q73624\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\
>   ccompiler.py", line 1013, in new_compiler
>       raise DistutilsPlatformError(msg) distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: don't know how to compile
>   C/C++ code on  platform 'nt' with 'cl2000' compiler

Is it possible to make cffi work with an embedded C compiler such as cl2000 ? Or is there a different approach to unit test C code written for a microcontroller with python ?